# IBM WORKLIGHT: Direct update not working when assign securityTest in application-description.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am testing under Android 2.2. My develop IDE is worklight 6.0.
When I remove the **securityTest** in *application-description.xml*, direct update works well. However, when added, it didn't work anymore.

```
 <android securityTest="mobileTests" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="true"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the actual public signing key of the certificate used to sign the APK, available by using the 'Extract public signing key' wizard.</publicSigningKey>
        </security>
    </android>
```

The problem is,if I remove secutiryTest. **customer authentication** meet url not found error and direct update work's fine.

The securityTest works fine.The following is the error I meet when remove securityTest. No other problems.

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url [project SCMProject]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
```

I want to know when does direct update happens, do securityTest have issue with it?
My goal is to achieve update version function. The API *WL.Client.getAppProperty (WL.AppProperty.LATEST_VERSION)* does not work.It returns *undefined*. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You fail to mention your scenario as well as any errors you see in LogCat; is it just DU that fails, or the app fails to connect? Provide logs (edit the question with the information)

Comment: does the security test works fine and please share the authenticationConfig.xml file information.

Comment: @IdanAdar no error in logCat. Connect failure when remove securityTest with 404 error(I use customer authentication, it need a url). Direct update not occur when add securityTest

Comment: @KawineshSK yes, it works well. Just won't direct update

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the web resources of the correct version? What version number is displayed next to the environment name in application-descriptor.xml? what version number is displayed in the app? you can see it in the Worklight Settings screen

Comment: What are you trying to do with this API method?

Comment: In any case, this API method indeed seems to not work; I have opened a defect for it.

Answer (score 1):

Security test is a layer of protection. Once you apply security test to your application you need to pass it before actually getting direct update. Once you're past your authentication you will receive direct update.

Comment: I do past authentication. But not direct update dialog show. Do I missed something, or you can tell how can I get the latest version of my app by worklight API -- WL.Client.getAppProperty (WL.AppProperty.LATEST_VERSION) does not work.Thanks

Comment: @vincent, this API is not meant for mobile envrionment; it's not that it doesn't work - it works, it's just not for mobile environments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ChallengeHandler, make sure that the submitSuccess method is call after successful auth. I had the same issue and Direct Update started working after making the call:

```
 var loginFormChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler(REALM_LTPA);
```

... after successful authentication

```
 loginFormChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 6.1, you have to use 6.1 Studio and 6.1 server. Deploy 6.0 Studio build binary to server has some issues with Direct Update.

Jerry